# How to correctly create an instance of JTable in joomla 3.x?

Tags: joomla

Here is my code in controller.php

```
class HelloWorldController extends JControllerLegacy
{
    public function addNew()
    {
    jimport('joomla.database.table');

    $db = JFactory::getDbo();

    $query = $db->getQuery(true)
        ->select('*')
        ->from('#__helloworld');

    $db->setQuery($query);
    $result = $db->loadObjectList();

    $table = JTable::getInstance('HelloWorldTableHellofour', '#__helloworld', array('dbo' => $db));
    }
}
```

I am using this link `http://localhost/joomla/index.php?option=com_helloworld&task=addnew`. When I do `print_r($result)`, it shows all the records. But when I do `print_r($table)` it shows a blank page. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

There really isn't enough code beyond your single class pulled from the controller to tell you why you are getting a blank page.

Have you tried to return the table? e.g.

```
class HelloWorldController extends JControllerLegacy
{
    public function addNew()
    {
    jimport('joomla.database.table');

    $db = JFactory::getDbo();

    $query = $db->getQuery(true)
        ->select('*')
        ->from('#__helloworld');

    $db->setQuery($query);
    $result = $db->loadObjectList();

    $table = JTable::getInstance('HelloWorldTableHellofour', '#__helloworld', array('dbo' => $db));

    return $table;
    }
}
```